# Have or contain

Tags: grammar

friends.

I want to know if I had written "have" instead of "contain" in the sentence below would make any difference.

Mr Jung said the magazine, to be printed in simplified Chinese characters, will 
**contain**  a mix of local content.

I have been studying for my CAE test and found this doubt.
Thanks.

Comment: *Include* sounds more natural to me (American English) than either of your two words. Meanwhile, yes, you can use *have* instead of *contain*.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't change the meaning per se but "contain" certainly reads as better English to me; using "have" just sounds off for some reason. As @Clare suggests in her comment above, you could also use "include" but this makes it more explicit that there will also be other content in the magazine whereas "contain" renders that interpretation less likely.